# How to force std::vector to use move constructor instead of the copy one?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, move-semantics

I want to use move semantics in my application, not to copy the data.
Here is the code:

```
using namespace std;

struct TestData
{
    TestData(const TestData&) = delete;
    TestData& operator=(const TestData&) = delete;
    TestData(TestData &&other) = default;
    TestData& operator=(TestData &&other) = default;

    TestData() { std::cout << "TestData()" << std::endl; }
    ~TestData() noexcept {
        if(ptr != null) delete []ptr;
        std::cout << "~TestData(), ptr = " << (ptr == nullptr ? "nullptr" : "not null") << std::endl; 
    }
    int x;
    char *ptr = nullptr;
};

void add(std::vector<TestData> &vector)
{
    TestData d;
    d.x = 1;
    d.ptr = new char[12];
    memcpy(d.ptr, "Test string", 11);
    vector.push_back(d);
}


int main()
{
    std::vector<TestData> v;
    add(v);
    add(v);

    return 0;
}
```

But the GCC compiler fails with the error:

> error: use of deleted function ‘TestData::TestData(const TestData&)’

But I don't want to copy the data, I want to move that. The reason is that copying data cause to copy the pointer (ptr) and so attempt to delete it in the destructor cause to double free corruption.

So the question - how to force that GCC will use move constructor?

- GCC v. 9.3.0
- Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: You want: `vector.push_back(std::move(d));`, but default move operations are wrong. `ptr` will be the same value in the target and in the source after move  operation performed. You have to add your own implementation, with clearing `ptr` to nullptr.

Comment: Instead of using `char*`, use `std::string`. That will eliminate the lurking bug in the current code, which creates a C-style string that is not nul-terminated. At the very least, use `strcpy` instead of `memcpy`; `strcpy` will properly terminate the string.

Comment: In addition to the null termination bug, the incorrect copy and move constructors lead to double delete -> undefined behavior.  So yes: _please_ use `std::string`

Comment: Also: the vector will always use the copy constructor internally unless your move constructor is declared `noexcept`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This call

```
vector.push_back(d);
```

does not call your move constructor, because `d` is not a r-value reference. It would be bad if move constructors would be called for non-r-value references, because it would rip of the guts out of objects that should stay intact. You need to cast to a r-value reference, to make explicit that you no longer need `d`. And thats what `std::move` does (it's really nothing but a cast):

```
vector.push_back(std::move(d));
```

However, the default move constructor of `TestData` is not doing the right thing. After the line above `ptr` is still owned by the moved from object resulting in a double delete. You can prevent that and the problem with your string not being null-terminated by using a `std::string` as member instead of the `char *`.

Comment: None of this is wrong (+1). For some reason though it bothers me saying that `std::move` "casts to an rvalue reference". It does return an rvalue reference to `T`, but the resulting expression is an rvalue expression of type `T` (_not_ reference type!). This rvalue expression of type `T` can then bind to the rvalue-ref-to-`T` parameter of push_back. So really it's having a _value_ that is an _rvalue_ that does the magic. Oh well :) (At least, I _think_ that's right? Reference collapsing makes my head hurt...)

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move): "It is exactly equivalent to a static_cast to an rvalue reference type."   thats good enough for me

Comment: Yeah I'm not saying it doesn't do that - it's about what happens to that result before it ends up bound to the function argument

Comment: I'm referring (no pun intended!) to [this](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prop#expr.type-1). The cast to `T&&` is just a way to get an rvalue of type `T`. It's that result that's passed to the function. So, yes, `std::move` is exactly what you say it is, but the reason this picks a move ctor or move overload is _not_ that you have two things of type `T&&` - it's that an rvalue `T` can bind to a `T&&` argument :)

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings fwiw, comments result only in one ping when the comment is first written. Only by chance I saw that you edited it.

Comment: Thanks @idclev463035818, that exactly what I need. Thanks for the detailed explanation. It seems that I did not understand the move semantics correctly, it's much clearer now.

Comment: thanks, I know - you'd see the edit when replying. Same as when you edited your own comment..